# recuperación de una imagen en base de datos ANGULAR

Tags: array, angular, blob, img

Mi pregunta es acerca de como puedo recuperar una imagen de la base de datos en angular 7?.

Anduve viendo los resultados que recibo de mi server y retorna `así`, ademas que cabe recalcar que todas las imágenes están almacenadas en **MySQL LONGBLOB**.

`{type: "Buffer", data: Array(27)}` (es la impresión en consola)

```js
this.querySubscription = this._backendService.getDiferentUser(this.found).subscribe((res) => {
        this.dataLoading = false;
        if (!res[0]) {
          this.user['Id_persona'] = '';
          this.notFound = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.notFound = false;
          }, 4000);
        } else {
          this.user = res[0];
          console.log(this.user['imagen']);
        }
```

y para mi imprecion en la imagen uso el `user.imagen`

```
 <img [src]="user.imagen" class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

Comment: Hola, tendrás que investigar un poco mas el APIque estas usando. El blob de MySQL te lo esta devolviendo en base64 o es un bytearray? Así, como se puede ver que tienes el API, lo mejor es que la misma te devuelva la imagen codificada en base64, para luego mostrarla _`<img [src]="data:image/png;base64, <<acá va el código que te pasaron en base64>>" />`_. Bueno, el texto completo de `data:....` lo armas en una variable dentro de tu modelo y eso es lo que le asingarias a [src]

Comment: me lo esa devolviendo en un bytearray pero muchas gracias investigare mas de como recibirlo de mi API